# Calling a C++ namespace-qualified function within a template function in another namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I have a default function 'foo' defined in a namespace in one header file:

```
//DefaultFoo.h
namespace DefaultFooNamespace
{
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T& x){/*...*/}
}
```

and overloads of foo defined in another namespace in one or more other header files, e.g., FooOverloads.h:

```
//FooOverloads.h
namespace FooOverloadsNamespace
{
    template <typename T>
    void foo(std::vector<T>& x){/*...*/}

    void foo(std::string& x){/*...*/}

    //etc.
}
```

and I have another function 'bar' which calls foo after bringing both DefaultFooNamespace and FooOverloadsNamespace namespaces into scope (note that I #include only DefaultFoo.h in Bar.h, as DefaultFoo.h contains a single function in a namespace which is intended never to be extended, unlike FooOverloadsNamespace which will be extended by the addition of additional overloads):

```
//Bar.h
#include "DefaultFoo.h" 

namespace BarNamespace
{
    template <typename T>
    void bar(T& x)
    {
        //... do stuff then call foo
        using DefaultFooNamespace::foo;
        using FooOverloadsNamespace::foo;
        foo(x);
    }
}
```

'bar' won't compile unless I either make sure FooOverloads.h is #include'd before a #include of Bar.h, or I make sure that FooOverloads.h is #include'd in Bar.h, or alternatively I provide a declaration of a 'foo' function for a dummy class in FooNamespace and #include that in Bar.h, e.g.

```
//Dummy.h:
struct DummyClass
{
private:
    DummyClass(){}
};
namespace FooNamespace
{
    inline void foo(DummyClass& x);  //purely to open up namespace
}

//Bar.h
#include "Dummy.h"
```

Is there any way around this, such that I can define bar and avoid having to create redundant code to open up FooNamespace in Bar?

Comment: what is Foo.h? what is App.h? Are you saying that `using FooOverloadsNamespace::foo;` fails to compile unless `FooOverloadsNamespace::foo` has been declared? Because that's how C++ works. Why can't you `#include "FooOverloads.h"` in Bar.h? Include what you use.

Comment: Sorry, edited to fix some of misnamed items. 
But basically what I am saying is that the FooOverloadsNamespace is intended to be extensible, and may be spread over several header files, but I have to arbitrarily select one of them for #inclusion in Bar.h.

Comment: That's not going to work. For the call `foo(x)` in `bar` to find the right overload it has to have seen that overload. You can't just include one overload, then expect `using FooOverloadsNamespace::foo` to magically make all overloads in all headers available.

Comment: is `FooNamespace` supposed to be `FooOverloadsNamespace`? If you do go with the dummy definition there's no need for a separate header, just put `namespace FooOverloadsNamespace { struct Dummy; void foo(Dummy&); }` at the top of Bar.h

Comment: Why do you say it is not going to work? Maybe I misexplained - if I #include one overload in bar.h, then call bar, it gets the correct overload, if the file/function which calls bar #includes the other overload .h files.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you are right.

Comment: Ah yes, it works _if_ the caller of `bar` has also included the definition of the right `foo` to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to get rid of the useless `DefaultFooNamespace` namespace.  Put the default `foo` in the same namespace as the overloads, then `bar` just does:

```
using FooNamespace::foo;
foo(x);
```

The default `foo` is used if the caller hasn't included a definition of a more appropriate one for the type of `x`

I don't see a reason for the default `foo` to be in a separate namespace, especially because doing that requires a separate dummy definition to make `bar` valid code, when the same overload could serve both purposes.

Comment: Hi, I have two namespaces so I can perform some other optimisations based on traits which determine whether the foo for a particular type is the one in the default namespace, or an optimised one provided in the Overload namespace. However, I was muddled in my thinking when I asked the question and your advice has been helpful, so I am happier now, so will mark your answer as accepted.